# Поиск по странам

Tags: поиск

Здравствуйте! Я новичок в разработке под ios, интересует как реализовать в приложении поиск, т.е. есть строка, в нее вводится первые буквы страны, а снизу высвечиваются результаты соответственно. Пожалуйста объясните все до мелочей. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Вот статья с описанием и рабочим примеров [How To Auto Complete With Custom Values](http://www.raywenderlich.com/336/auto-complete-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-auto-complete-with-custom-values)

Comment: Есть еще готовый компонент MLPAutoCompleteTextField на github https://github.com/EddyBorja/MLPAutoCompleteTextField

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку! https://github.com/EddyBorja/MLPAutoCompleteTextField - не совсем понял как устанавливать на чистый проект с View Controller, подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: @Davel, там же есть демонстрационный проект.

Comment: @huffman к сожалению мои знания слишком малы, я не смог это перенести в свою "программу". импортировал файлы, скопировал строку поиска, что еще надо?

Comment: @Davel, может в таком случае вам лучше начать с чего-то более простого.